# Подскажите библиотеки для имитации нажатий клавиш

Tags: python, selenium, sendmessage, whatsapp

Пишу на python рассылку для what's app. Столкнулся с банальной проблемой, которую не могу решить. А именно: перенос ввода текста на новую строку, ну или через 2 строки. Может вы поделитесь альтернативой, но при использовании "\n" строку не переносит, а просто отправляет сообщение. Делаю это на selenium и уже попробовал ActionChains, не помогло(но может я не так использую конечно, но вроде, все правильно. Заметил, что при переносе строки вотс создает отдельный р class. Все до чего додумался на данный момент - это уже какая-нибудь библиотека, которая в наглую будет прожимать две кнопка(shift+enter).

[image: класс в вотсе]

```
    tex = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p')
    tex.send_keys('тут всякий текст')
    time.sleep(5)
    ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.SHIFT) 
    time.sleep(3)
    tex.send_keys('тут тоже всякий текс')
    tex.send_keys('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Парни, я понял как нужно было сделать. Я ломал голову долгое время, но особо не задумывался. Короче, если кто-то столкнется с такой же проблемой. Я спасу твои пару дней ожидания. Держи код:

```
ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.ENTER).key_up(
                    Keys.SHIFT).key_up(Keys.BACKSPACE).perform()
```